# Unable to create hive table for hbase

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, integration

I am running with hive version 1.1.0 , Hbase version 1.0.1 and hadoop version 2.7.0. Now for the below command I am getting error

```html
hive> CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(eid int, ename string, esal double) 
    > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
    > ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cfstr:enm,cfsal:esl")
    > TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "emp1");
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V
```

If I create a table in HBase and refer that from Hive using external table, that is working fine.

In the hive home I have created an auxlib directory and copied the below jar files.

```html
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hive/auxlib$ ls
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar       commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar       hbase-checkstyle-1.0.1.jar      hbase-protocol-1.0.1.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar  commons-io-2.4.jar                 hbase-client-1.0.1.jar          hbase-rest-1.0.1.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar               commons-lang-2.6.jar               hbase-common-1.0.1.jar          hbase-server-1.0.1.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar             commons-logging-1.1.3.jar          hbase-common-1.0.1-tests.jar    hbase-server-1.0.1-tests.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar     commons-math-2.1.jar               hbase-examples-1.0.1.jar        hbase-shell-1.0.1.jar
commons-compiler-2.7.6.jar        commons-pool-1.5.4.jar             hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.0.1.jar  hbase-testing-util-1.0.1.jar
commons-compress-1.4.1.jar        commons-vfs2-2.0.jar               hbase-hadoop-compat-1.0.1.jar   hbase-thrift-1.0.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar     guava-14.0.1.jar                   hbase-it-1.0.1.jar              hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar              hbase-annotations-1.0.1.jar        hbase-it-1.0.1-tests.jar        zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar          hbase-annotations-1.0.1-tests.jar  hbase-prefix-tree-1.0.1.jar
```

The below details are set in .bashrc file

```html
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0/
export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
#alias java="`which java` -Dwhatever"

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB=$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib
export HADOOP_TOOLS_LIB=$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export HIVE_HOME="/usr/lib/hive"
export HBASE_HOME="/usr/lib/hbase"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HIVE_HOME/bin:$HBASE_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_COMMON_LIB:$HADOOP_TOOLS_LIB:$PATH
```

Can you please suggest what is wrong here actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got fixed after using hbase version 0.98.14 with hive version 1.1.0; plz visit `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701905/unable-to-load-data-in-hbase-table-‌​‌​from-hive` for details

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the `hbase.jar`

First check your `hive-site.xml` file for the property `hive.aux.jars.path` and make sure `hbase.jar`, `zookeeper.jar` & `hive-hbase-handlerXXXX.jar` are specified.

After that, enter into the hive shell and run `list jars` to make sure they've been loaded. You can also load them manually (for your current session) with the command `add jar [your-jar].jar`

---

Additionally, if you don't want to mess with configuration files, you can create your own .hiverc file in your home path with your preferred initialization commands, i.e:

```
SET hive.cli.print.header=true;
SET hbase.scan.cacheblock=0;
SET hbase.scan.cache=10000;
SET hbase.client.scanner.cache=10000;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/zookeeper.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/hbase.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.10.0-cdh4.7.1.jar;
...
```

Comment: Yes hive.aux.jars.path was missing previously.

Comment: I have added this for zookeeper-3.4.6.jar,hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0.jar,guava-14.0.1.jar,hbase-common-1.0.1.jar,hbase-client-1.0.1.jar,hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.0.1.jar,hbase-hadoop-compat-1.0.1.jar,commons-configuration-1.6.jar                                                                                            In hive_env.sh I have set HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH, 
JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, HIVE_HOME and PATH

Comment: hive> list jars;
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-common-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/guava-14.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-client-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.0.1.jar

Comment: SAME ERROR:                                                                                      hive> CREATE TABLE tblHbase(key int, a int, b int,c bigint)
    > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
    > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,f:a,f:b,f:c")
    > TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name"="tblHbase");
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)

Comment: Can anyone help me on the above issue please

Comment: You're still missing `hbase.jar`, also make sure you've set the zookeeper quorum `SET hbase.zookeeper.quorum=ZOOKEEPER_SERVER1,ZOOKEEPER_SERVER2;` so it can find the HBase regionservers (`SET -v` to see all variables). For more info check this: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_10.html

Comment: If you see my post I am using Hbase version 1.0.1 and in this version there is no havse<version>.jar exists. Whatever jars exists (name starting with Hbase) I have added in the path. But having same error.

Comment: hive (koushik)> list jars;
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-common-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/guava-14.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-shell-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-it-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar

Comment: /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serde-1.1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-thrift-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-rest-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-client-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-server-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar

Comment: /usr/lib/hive/auxlib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-prefix-tree-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-annotations-1.0.1.jar
/usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar
/usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hbase-protocol-1.0.1.jar

Comment: All the above jars I have added in the hive path. Still the same error. Please let me know if anything else I have do.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't noticed it was 1.0.1. According to http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/cdh_ig_hive_hbase.html the only jar you're missing is htrace-core.jar, you can try to add it but I don't think the error is related to it. I'm out of ideas otherwise, I've tried your statement and it works perfectly.

Comment: No still the same issue after adding htrace-core.jar. By anychance did you tried with the same versions of hadoop, hive and hbase on which I am trying.

Comment: Nope, too new for me ;) Tested Hadoop 2.6, Hive 0.14, both HBase 0.94 & 0.98 (cloudera & hdp), had to manually load jars but everything worked ok.

Comment: Is it possible for you just to test with the versions I am working. Being an expert you might be able to provide the resolution for the problem then.

Comment: if you want I can upload my version (on which I am working) in some place, so that you don't have spend time for configuring

Comment: I am still struggling with it, can anyone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

At the current time, according to [HBaseIntegration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration)

> Hive 2.x **will** be compatible with HBase 1.x and higher. (See
>   [HIVE-10990](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10990) for details.) Consumers wanting to work with HBase 1.x
>   using Hive 1.x will need to compile Hive 1.x stream code themselves.

In short, until Hive 2.x release, you need to compile the Hive 1.x stream code yourself!

Comment: Could you please let me know steps to compile Hive 1.x stream code

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-BuildingHivefromSource

Comment: I have changed the hbase version to 0.98.14-hadoop2 and with that I am successfully able to create the table but I am unable to insert data. Could you please have a look in the post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701905/unable-to-load-data-in-hbase-table-from-hive` and suggest

Comment: Since both of your issues are fixed, you may want to accept the answers :)

Comment: This issue fixed after using hbase version 0.98.14 with hive 1.1.0 ... plz visit `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701905/unable-to-load-data-in-hbase-table-‌​from-hive` for detail

Comment: In general, either you find an answer for this question or not. If you found, please post your solution as an answer, not a comment, and accept it. Or if any of the other answers are correct, accept them!

Answer (score 0):

To day I got same issue, and build hive-src again with new pom.xml config 
Please refer and change this line in **pom.xml**
 `enter code here`**1.1.2**

Note: I use Hadoop 2.7.1, Hive 1.2.1 and Hbase 1.1.2

Comment: <hbase.hadoop2.version>1.1.2</hbase.hadoop2.version>