# unable to load data in hbase table from hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I am using hadoop version 2.7.0, hive version 1.1.0, HBase version hbase-0.98.14-hadoop2.

I have created a hbase table from hive successfully.

```html
hive (Koushik)> CREATE TABLE hive_hbase_emp_test(eid int, ename string, esal double) 
              > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
              > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES 
              > ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cfstr:enm,cfsal:esl")
              > TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "hive_hbase_emp_test");
OK
Time taken: 0.874 seconds

hbase(main):004:0> describe 'hive_hbase_emp_test'
Table hive_hbase_emp_test is ENABLED                                                                                                            
hive_hbase_emp_test                                                                                                                             
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                     
{NAME => 'cfsal', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VER
SIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}                
{NAME => 'cfstr', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VER
SIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}                
2 row(s) in 3.0650 seconds
```

But when I am trying to load the table from hive it is failing.

```html
hive (Koushik)> INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE hive_hbase_emp_test SELECT empid,empname,empsal FROM hive_employee;
Query ID = hduser_20150921110000_249675d5-9da7-49fe-b03e-3a2d813ac898
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1442836788507_0011, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1442836788507_0011/
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1442836788507_0011
Hadoop job information for Stage-0: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2015-09-21 11:01:39,041 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-09-21 11:02:39,429 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-09-21 11:02:45,814 Stage-0 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1442836788507_0011 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1442836788507_0011_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1442836788507_0011

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_1442836788507_0011_m_000000

URL:
  http://0.0.0.0:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1442836788507_0011&tipid=task_1442836788507_0011_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:449)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
 at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
 ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
 ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
 ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:147)
 ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyUtils.getByte(Ljava/lang/String;B)B
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySerDeParameters.collectSeparators(LazySerDeParameters.java:223)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySerDeParameters.<init>(LazySerDeParameters.java:90)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDeParameters.<init>(HBaseSerDeParameters.java:95)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe.initialize(HBaseSerDe.java:117)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.initializeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:344)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:469)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:425)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.initializeOp(SelectOperator.java:65)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:469)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:425)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.initializeOp(TableScanOperator.java:193)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.initializeOp(MapOperator.java:427)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:385)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:126)
 ... 22 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

The content of auxlib folder in hive is as below

```html
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hive/auxlib$ ls
activation-1.1.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar
apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar
api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar
api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar
asm-3.1.jar
avro-1.7.4.jar
aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
azure-storage-2.0.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-codec-1.7.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
commons-configuration-1.6.jar
commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-el-1.0.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-math-2.1.jar
commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
commons-net-3.1.jar
curator-client-2.7.1.jar
curator-framework-2.7.1.jar
curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar
findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar
gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar
grizzly-framework-2.1.2.jar
grizzly-http-2.1.2.jar
grizzly-http-server-2.1.2.jar
grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.2.jar
grizzly-rcm-2.1.2.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
guava-12.0.1.jar
guice-3.0.jar
guice-servlet-3.0.jar
hadoop-annotations-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-ant-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-archives-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-auth-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-aws-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-azure-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar
hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar
hadoop-datajoin-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-distcp-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-extras-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-gridmix-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-hdfs-2.7.0-tests.jar
hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.0-tests.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-openstack-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-rumen-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-sls-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-streaming-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.0.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.0.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
hbase-annotations-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-checkstyle-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-client-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-common-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-common-0.98.14-hadoop2-tests.jar
hbase-examples-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-hadoop2-compat-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-hadoop-compat-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-it-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-it-0.98.14-hadoop2-tests.jar
hbase-prefix-tree-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-protocol-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-resource-bundle-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-rest-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-server-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-server-0.98.14-hadoop2-tests.jar
hbase-shell-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-testing-util-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
hbase-thrift-0.98.14-hadoop2.jar
high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar
hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar
hive-serde-1.2.1.jar
htrace-core-2.04.jar
htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar
httpclient-4.1.3.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.1.3.jar
httpcore-4.2.5.jar
jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.8.8.jar
jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar
jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar
jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar
jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar
javax.servlet-3.1.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
jcodings-1.0.8.jar
jersey-client-1.8.jar
jersey-core-1.8.jar
jersey-core-1.9.jar
jersey-grizzly2-1.9.jar
jersey-guice-1.9.jar
jersey-json-1.9.jar
jersey-server-1.9.jar
jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.jar
jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar
jets3t-0.9.0.jar
jettison-1.1.jar
jettison-1.3.1.jar
jetty-6.1.26.jar
jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar
jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
joda-time-2.7.jar
joni-2.1.2.jar
jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar
jsch-0.1.42.jar
jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar
jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar
jsp-api-2.1.jar
jsr305-3.0.0.jar
junit-4.11.jar
leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar
libthrift-0.9.0.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar
metrics-core-3.0.1.jar
mockito-all-1.8.5.jar
netty-3.6.6.Final.jar
paranamer-2.3.jar
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar1
snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
xmlenc-0.52.jar
xz-1.0.jar
zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
```

What's I am missing here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I made a mistake. I have kept `hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar` & `hive-serde-1.2.1.jar` in the auxlib path, which was causing the problem. When I removed 1.2.1 version of jars and then it is working fine with `hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0.jar` & `hive-serde-1.1.0.jar`. So the problem resolved with hive version 1.1.0 only (with habse version 0.98.14 and hadoop version 2.7.0).

Comment: Could you give some clarity on that. I didnt get that removing jars part. Iam facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a version compatibility issue. The `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyUtils.getByte` is added to this class in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/hive/commit/e5fa88d317f6b1f26b01aef16d5d5e54a00cf714), which is released in Hive 1.2. See [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9500)

Comment: Actually I made a mistake. I have kept `hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1.jar` & `hive-serde-1.2.1.jar` in the auxlib path, which was causing the problem. When I removed 1.2.1 version of jars and then it is working fine with `hive-hbase-handler-1.1.0.jar` & `hive-serde-1.1.0.jar`. So the problem resolved with hive version 1.1.0 only (with habse version 0.98.14 and hadoop version 2.7.0).

Comment: That make sense because hive-hbase-hbandler-1.2.1 doesn't work with Hive 1.1.0

Answer (score -1):

NoSuchMethodError represents JVM could find the Class, but the Method is not found.
May be the class(runtime), is not the same with your hive version.
You can start hive cli in debug mode(bin/hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console). It will show all jars in and find the jar version in the logs.